# Getting Null rows from resultset

Tags: java, sql, javafx

In this code I am trying to get the resultset from database but I am getting zero as output when I do rs.getRow(). Everything seems to be correct .

package application;

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

public class FlightsController {

    private String from_airport;

    private String to_airport;

    private Date departure_date;

    public void fillTable(ActionEvent event)
    {   
        HomePageController homepage = new HomePageController();

        from_airport=homepage.getFrom();

        to_airport=homepage.getTo();

        try 
        {
            ResultSet rs;
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl2","scott","root");
            Statement st=con.createStatement();
            String sql=" select * from routes";
            rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
            System.out.println(rs.getRow());
            rs.close();         
            con.close();
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

In this code I am trying to get the resultset from database but I am getting zero as output when I do re.getRow(). Everything seems to be correct .

What is going wrong? 
Pls help

Comment: Have you tried rs.next() or rs.nextResult() before you do rs.getRow()?

Comment: [mcve] please .. (and start using java naming conventions _now_ that is in your next question :) This snippet was enough to see the error in regard to the backend, but then the problem is basically unrelated to javafx (please keep the tags focused on the problem)

Comment: .. regarding the fx-part that I'm seeing here (and as Fabian already noted in your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/q/61570379/203657 ) - instantiating a controller without loading it is _wrong_ because a) its fields are not injected and b) another instance than you expect. Please work through a basic tutorial on fxml, practice by modifying smaller parts and only when confident on the basics, go ahead for a complexer project :)

Comment: What are you actually expecting to get? This would seem to be the expected result (see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getRow())).

Answer (score 0):

Before you get a row, you need to call:

```
rs.next();
```

Please see this tutorial:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html
for information on how to use `ResultSet`s.

The method `getRow()` gives the number of the current row, in your code, you are *before* the first row.
See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getRow()

Hope this helps.